# java protected access not compiling

Tags: java, protected

The problem is about protected access. What is wrong with this code :

```
package pkgA; 
public class Foo { 
    protected int b = 6; 
} 

package pkgB; 
import pkgA.*; 

class Food extends Foo { 
    void met(){
        System.out.println(new Food().b);
    } 
}; 

public class Baz { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Food fd = new Food(); 
        fd.met();  // *line 1* 
        System.out.println(" " + fd.b); // *line 2*; error : b has          protected access in Foo 
    } 
}
```

Why line 1 is good but line 2 not?

Comment: Why do you think it _should_ work? Please explain your thinking

Comment: `met()` is a package-protected method, so accessible from `Baz` as it is apparently in the same package. `b` is protected, so accessible from `Food` as a subclass but not `Baz` as it is not a subclass.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `b` from `Baz`, which isn't possible, because `b` is `protected`. Only classes that derive from `Foo` can access `b`.

You can access `met()` because it has no access modifier, and hence it is accesible for classes within the same package (both `Baz` and `Food` are in the same package).

This is basic inheritence by the way. More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html.

Comment: I don't understand, b is accessed by instance fd of class Food and Food extend Foo. Food is a subclass of Foo, b is accessed by inheritance. Why fd.met() can access b but fd.b not ?

Comment: `Food` is in the same package as `Baz` and `met()` has no access modifier.